# Spring: how to set multiple properties through autowiring?

Tags: java, spring, properties, autowired

In all the examples of autowiring that I have found, the example is about one `<bean>` `autowire` attribute which is set for example to `byName`, and the  has only one property value which is supposed to be set through autowiring.

My question is what if a `<bean>` has multiple properties that you want to set through autowiring?  No one seems to explain that situation.  Can someone explain if I can or if I should use `autowire` to set multiple properties in a bean?  The following is an example of such a situation where I want to set the account and credit properties of the customer bean by autowiring:

```
<beans>
    <bean name="customer" class="ultratech.com.Customer" autowire="byName">
         <bean name="account"/>
         <bean name="credit>
    </beam>

    <bean name="account" class="ultratech.com.Account"/>
    <bean name="credit" class="ultratech.com.Credit"/>
</beans>
```

Also, please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I were to use annotation (`@Autowire`), then my problem is easily solved, since I would be able to add `@Autowire` to any property of a bean separately.

Comment: What you mean is wiring beans via XML right In that case, this is not autowiring, it is just wiring since you have to do it manually ;)

Comment: Multiple properties in the bean? Or multiple values? Multiple values will surely fail as Spring cannot resolve what to associate. So please explain with a sample code fragment.

Comment: I've added example to make my question clear.

Comment: I've updated my response to match your clarified question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT: edited to reflect on updated question]

Your question is much more clear right now. You seem to think (if I follow your thinking properly), that in the `autowire="byName"` you are supposed to provide a bean name instead of `byName` value.
That is not correct. The autowire attribute can take a few possible values and `byName` is one of those. When you set `autowire` to `byName` like here:

```
<bean name="someBean" class="foo.bar.Baz" autowire="byName />
```

then Spring will look at all the fields in `someBean` (`foo.bar.Baz` class) and attempt to wire all fields of this object on a per name basis. That is, (in your case) if a Customer class has a field `account`, Spring will look in its context and try to find a bean with name `account` to inject into the Customer bean.

If you define two such beans:

```
 <bean name="customer" class="ultratech.com.Customer" autowire="byName" />
 <bean name="account" class="ultratech.com.Account" />
```

then you are good to, if Customer is a class along this lines:

```
public class Customer {
    (...)
    private Account account;
    (...)
}
```

Here is what your XML code snippet should look like, assuming that your Customer class has fields named account and credit:

```
<beans>
    <bean name="customer" class="ultratech.com.Customer" autowire="byName" />
    <bean name="account" class="ultratech.com.Account" />
    <bean name="credit" class="ultratech.com.Credit" />
</beans>
```

Apart from "byName" autowiring, you can autowire:

1. no - default - no autowiring
2. byType - looks for a bean of the property type - be wary, though - only one bean of this type is allowed for autowiring byType; if there is more then one an exception is raised
3. constructor - works just like byType, but looks for constructor parameters only; all of constructor parameters have to be satisfied with exactly one bean of each respective type

See Spring reference for more info:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire